# Error en método listar con ASP.NET Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Soy nuevo en lo que es c# Asp.net con Entity. La situación  es que estoy haciendo un método listar donde me traiga los datos de a tabla padre con sus hijos, pero no logro hacer que e traiga todos, solo me trae hasta clientes, en el método se ve.

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<MedicionPrincipal>> GetMedicion(int id)            
    {            
        var MedicionPrincipal = await _context.MedicionPrincipal.FirstOrDefaultAsync( m=> m.IdMedicion == id);

        if (MedicionPrincipal == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(MedicionPrincipal);
    }
```

Esta bien formulado o me pueden guiar de alguna otra manera de hacerlo, 
también he visto que el método `foreach` puede hacerlo, o si me recomiendan algún link la verdad no he encontrado nada bueno.

---

esta es la padre

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SMAD_Entidades.Models
{
  public partial class MedicionPrincipal
  {
    public int IdMedicion { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Fecha { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Hora { get; set; }
    public string TipoActividad { get; set; }
    public string Simap { get; set; }
    public string Lugar { get; set; }
    public double? Tarifa { get; set; }
    public double? Ciclo { get; set; }
    public string Localizacion { get; set; }
    public string CentroServicio { get; set; }
    public string SubEstacion { get; set; }
    public string Circuito { get; set; }
    public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }

    public virtual Cliente IdClienteNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario IdUsuarioNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Medidor Medidor { get; set; }
    public virtual Movimiento Movimiento { get; set; }
  }
}
```

esta es una tabla hija

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SMAD_Entidades.Models
{
  public partial class Medidor
  {
    public int IdMedidor { get; set; }
    public int? Nise { get; set; }
    public double? ConstanteFacturacion { get; set; }

    public virtual MedicionPrincipal IdMedidorNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual LecServicio LecServicio { get; set; }
    public virtual MedidorInstalado MedidorInstalado { get; set; }
    public virtual MedidorRespaldo MedidorRespaldo { get; set; }
    public virtual MedidorRetirado MedidorRetirado { get; set; }
    public virtual Totalizado Totalizado { get; set; }
    public virtual Transformador Transformador { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Indica por favor el código de las tablas padre e hija (Modelos). Y también el texto del error que te da.

Comment: listo señor ya los subi

Comment: Por favor añade el código faltante pero en tu pregunta amigo, pues lo publicaste como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es traer los datos de tu tabla `Medidor` debes incluirla en la consulta con `Include()`:

```
var MedicionPrincipal = await _context.MedicionPrincipal
         .Include (m => m.Medidor)
         .FirstOrDefaultAsync( m => m.IdMedicion == id);
```

Comment: hola, si asi lo puse , el detalle es que esa medidor, trae 2hijas, y no me las trae

Comment: @WilberthRomero Tienes tus modelos mal construidos. Si Medidor trae más de un registro debes definirlo como una lista List<Medidor> Medidor, y añadir la relación con la tabla  Medidor a través de la clave IdMedidor.

Comment: También como te indicó @aprendiz, indica los modelos en la pregusta, no en una respuesta. Luego elimina la respuesta.

Comment: listo, ya pude solucionarlo, tenias razon con el list\

Comment: @WilberthRomero Estupendo!. Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta.

Comment: @WilberthRomero Recuerda también marcar el check verde al lado de la respuesta que te ha solucionado la pregunta, con eso estarás colaborando con la buena salud de este sitio. Gracias.